# Cron job to call php to email last 24 hours posts

Tags: php, email, cron

We have been trying to call via CronJob a PHP script that will email the past 24 hours posts using the `'post_type' = 'reservations'` filter.

```
<?php
  query_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'reservations', 'showposts' => 10 ) );
  if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
?>
<?php _res_name; ?>

<?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

I know this is wrong but for the life of me I cannot get my head round the sequence for this.

Any advice?

Comment: that's the only code? Post your cron code and the part where you are mailing this data.

Comment: Hi @Dot1, I am using the Crony Cronjob Manager that handles the mailing and cronjob itself. I am just puting the PHP in the custom PHP script section itself...

Comment: have you tried opening this page separately, check if it prints anything, because the code seems to be fine and the cronmanager might not be working?

Answer (score 0):

In your functions.php you can use this. You will have to activate your theme again for it to take effect. You only want to schedule a cron job on activation, not on activation NOT on every page load, which is what the functions.php does, it loads on every page load.

This would be betterused in a plugin.

```
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'cron_job_activation_hook');

function cron_job_activation_hook() {
wp_schedule_event( time(), 'daily', 'ron_posts_emails');
}

add_action('ron_posts_emails', 'ron_send_daily_posts_email');

function ron_send_daily_posts_email() {
$args = array(
'numberposts' => 10,     
'orderby' => 'post_date',  
'order' => 'DESC',       
'post_type' => 'reservations',    
'post_status' => 'draft, publish, future, pending, private',    
'suppress_filters' => true );    
$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args, $output = ARRAY_A );

//mail stuff hurr

}
```

Comment: Thanks for this Ron, will give it a try. The plugin I am using the Crony Cronjob Manager which allows a custom PHP section for the job. It automatically takes care of the mail mailings whihc I have set to every 24 hours.

Comment: I would say it would be more complicated to do it that way than to just save this in a really simple plugin and edit it as necessary. I can continue this and make it into a small plugin if you don't get that to work. Lmk